# Flash Builder variables

Tags: flash, flash-builder

Ok, I'm at my wits' end. I'm a noob and I get that, and it's been awhile since I've done programming with any sincerity. That said, I'm trying to get back into it and running into problems left and right.

My biggest problem has to do with assigning variables. As a side project, I'm trying to create a simple calculator using FlashBuilder. I know it's not done, and it probably has multiple problems. So any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Here's my code thus far. WHAT. AM. I. MISSING???

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import spark.components.FormItem
        import spark.components.TextArea;
        import spark.components.TextInput;

        public var n_1:Number
        public var n_2:Number
        public var ttl:Number = 0


    protected function added():void
    {
    ttl = n1 + n2;
    total.text = String(ttl);

    }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>



<fx:Declarations>

    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>


<s:Form id="Calc" x="28" y="27">
    <s:FormItem id="n1" label="1st #">
        <s:TextInput prompt="Number"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem id="n2" label="2nd#">
        <s:TextInput prompt="Number"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="Total=">
        <s:Label id="total"/>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
<s:Button id="add_bn" x="377" y="83" label="+" click="added()"/>
<s:Button id="minus_bn" x="377" y="123" label="-"/>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a form item with another form item, thus receiving not a number (`NaN`).

What you need is the `TextInput` text values as a `Number`.

You could also make use of data binding, but to work with your example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955"
               minHeight="600">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.components.FormItem;
            import spark.components.TextInput;

            public var n_1:Number;
            public var n_2:Number;
            public var ttl:Number = 0;

            protected function add_bn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                // get numbers from text field
                n_1 = Number(n1.text);
                n_2 = Number(n2.text);

                // total:
                ttl = n_1 + n_2;

                total.text = ttl.toString();
            }

            protected function minus_bn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                // get numbers from text field
                n_1 = Number(n1.text);
                n_2 = Number(n2.text);

                // total:
                ttl = n_1 - n_2;

                total.text = ttl.toString();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:Form id="Calc"
            x="28"
            y="27">
        <s:FormItem label="1st #">
            <s:TextInput id="n1"
                         prompt="Number" />
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="2nd#">
            <s:TextInput id="n2"
                         prompt="Number" />
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Total=">
            <s:Label id="total" />
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>
    <s:Button id="add_bn"
              x="377"
              y="83"
              label="+"
              click="add_bn_clickHandler(event)" />
    <s:Button id="minus_bn"
              x="377"
              y="123"
              label="-"
              click="minus_bn_clickHandler(event)" />
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm a noob, I'll ask... Why the need to make the function name longer? I understand the 'clickHandler' had to be on their, but is the rest including the underscore necessary or just for clarity? Thanks again!

Comment: The name is totally up to you - doesn't really matter.  Actually, since I added both add and subtract methods, I just [ctrl+space] auto-generated the method stubs using Flash Builder.  It also added the event, which was missing from your function.  'Handler' or 'onClick' naming conventions are not necessary, but nice.  No problem with what you had.

Comment: Got it. And thanks I have another question, and not sure if I should ask here or create a new question... but how do I get it to do it over and over? I get how to do an If Else loop or and Until loop, but do I need to put this code into a separate class and then put it inside the loop or do something else?

Comment: Not sure I follow - it executes upon pressing the add / subtract buttons, so you can recalculate as you desire.  You could add a clear button for the next calculation.  You could place this code in an MXML component if you want to reuse it in many places.  I'm not sure what you want to loop.  Might be easier to answer in a separate question, or let me know what you're trying to accomplish in your loop.

Comment: I'll ask another question. This was just a starting point. But THANK YOU for your answers thus far!